# Radio button functionality on a UIView in custom table cell

Tags: iphone

I have a custom table cell having a uiview and 3 labels. on the uiview there is an imageview. i am detecting touch and on the uiview/imageview. on touchesended method i am changing the image of the imageview on this uiview.now after running the program 7 rows are visible on the table. if i touch on the imageview of 1st row, the image gets changed. Now if i scroll the table, the image of the imageview on row 9th also gets changed itself. Can any one pls help me out whats getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you use reusable cells, after scrolling the table view will consume the same cells you've set up in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. So it might be that the cell for row 1 and for row 9 use the same cell object. That explains, that when you change something in row 1 cell, the row 9 cell will be changed in the same way. Just be sure, that when you setup your reusable cells to nil the image of your uiimageview, or feed it with a proper image.